# How can I “replace all” in Acrobat Pro DC?

Tags: adobe-acrobat, window, find-and-replace

How can I "replace all" in Acrobat Pro DC?

I can only find "replace":

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible in one action in Adobe Acrobat Pro DC (I have it here).

Find and Replace (as you did) and after the first Replace click on Next and do that until done.

Here is a supporting Acrobat article.

[Adobe Replace All](https://answers.acrobatusers.com/Find-Replace-ALL-q249213.aspx)

> Voted Best Answer Open the Find dialog (Ctrl or Cmd + F).
>
> Enter "XYZ". For the replace with use "ABC".
>
> Click "next" and then "replace" . Continue with click'n the "replace
> next".
>
> One at a time - click & it is replaced, click & it is replaced, ....,
> until it is done.
>
> And that'll result in you having replaced all "XYZ" in one go.

Answer (score 0):

Acrobat Pro's Redact tools can do it.

Found here:

https://community.adobe.com/t5/acrobat-discussions/batch-processing-search-and-replace-text-in-several-thousand-pdf-files/td-p/10950200

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).